# Android Twilio what does "make an HTTP POST to your Messages list resource URI" mean?

Tags: java, android, twilio

I am trying to do the simple Twilio integration to send an SMS from my tablet.  Following the Java documentation, I've made a new java class `SmsSender.java` but now it says

> To send a new outgoing message, make an HTTP POST to your Messages list resource URI:
>
> `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages`

[View example here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)

I don't know how to send an HTTP POST in android (though, I can research that easily), but what is this URL? Where is it pointing to?  If I already have a class with all of the required information, how do I "make an HTTP POST to your Messages list resource URI"?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Couple of things that you need to know here.

Firstly, the full URL you need to make the HTTP POST request to is:

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages
```

Where you fill in `{AccountSid}` with your credentials that you can find on your Twilio dashboard.

The API documentation normally uses the shorthand of skipping the full URL just to make things more readable. You can find the basics, including the base URL, on the [Twilio REST API here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest).

Secondly, we do not actually recommend making calls to our REST API from within client side (Android, iOS, JavaScript) applications. This is because to do so you would need to include your Account SID and Auth Token as part of the application and a malicious attacker could decompile the application, extract your Twilio credentials and use them, spending money on your account.

Instead, we recommend you make calls to the Twilio API from a server you control on which you can store your account credentials with no worry of leaking them. If you are looking to build something like this also in Java the Twilio site has a [quick start guide on sending SMS messages with Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/sending-via-rest). You can find quick starts in other languages too, as well as some more [in depth tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/eta-notifications/java/servlets).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you @philnash!  That's some good information.  The app I'm developing is a photo booth app and I'd like to include an MMS option.  I've talked with one of the twilio CSAs and she suggested I look into the Connect-Overview (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/connect-overview).  I'd like the user to be able to log in to their own account on the app, then be able to send photos when the pictures are taken.  I was using the code above only to test the API and try to understand better.  I have no idea where to start, really since I'm new to Android all together.